# The tags [friendly-url] and [clean-urls] seem to be about the same thing

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

[friendly-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendly-url) (676):

> A friendly URL is a website address that does not contain a query string or complex strings in the URI, instead relying on a human-readable, SEO-friendly resource path after the website authority (e.g. `http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendly-url`).

[clean-urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-urls) (289):

> Clean URLs are purely structural URLs that do not contain a query string and instead contain only the path of the resource.

---

They seem to be about the same concept. I think we should only have *one* tag.

As [clean-urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-urls) uses plural and is used on less questions, I guess [friendly-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendly-url) is the better candidate to keep.